# Uploading video to Facebook with Facebook iOS SDK 3.x

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, video

I found quite some solutions to uploading video with the facebook SDK, but none of them work (including the information from the facebook developer blog). Here is the code I'm using to upload a video. The "out_composed.mov" is created successfully, as I can save that video in the gallery or send it via email.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* composedOutputPath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out_composed.mov"];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:composedOutputPath];

NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject>* params = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
[params setDictionary:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       videoData, @"video.mov",
                       @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                       @"My awesome video", @"title", nil]];

if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen)
{
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"offline_access", @"publish_stream",@"user_videos",@"video_upload",nil] allowLoginUI:true completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
                           {
                               FBRequest* uploadVideoRequest = [FBRequest requestForPostWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos" graphObject:params];
                               [uploadVideoRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
                                {
                                    // The server returns "353 missing video file" here.
                                    if(error != nil) NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
                                    else NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                }];
                           }];
    appDelegate.session = [FBSession activeSession];
} else
{
    FBRequest* uploadVideoRequest = [FBRequest requestForPostWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos" graphObject:params];
    [uploadVideoRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         if(error != nil) NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
         else NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1fdc94a0 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 353;
            message = "(#353) Missing video file";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Heiko

Comment: Have you tried mime-encoding the video before attaching it to the request? (that is just a stab in the dark though)

Comment: I'm using an AVAssetExportSession to export a composed movie. I assume that the encoding is handled by either AVAssetExportSession or AVAssetWriter. It is playing fine if I save or send it via email.

Comment: Are you sure videoData contains data? "Missing video file" could be related.

Comment: Yes, I have a callback in my exporter, which notifies its delegate about completion of export. When I save to iOS gallery with the exact same file, it works. Creating an email with this file works. Only when trying to construct the Facebook upload, it fails.

Comment: I read, that for uploading videos, one shall use the http://graph-video.facebook... URL, but there is no obvious way of doing that.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/samples/Hackbook/Hackbook/APICallsViewController.m#L712 uses "me/videos" instead of "/me/videos"

Comment: Tried that too, same error :-/

Comment: you should try the @"file" or @"source" key for your video data in the Graph Object

Comment: Ok. The SDK creates the URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos?format=json&sdk=ios&access_token which is incorrect for video uploads. The only solution is to roll your own HTTP POST request. I will post a solution as soon as I got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me using the 3.0.8 SDK (using `-requestWithGraphPath:...` instead of `-requestForPostWithGraphPath:...`):

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:videoData forKey:@"sample.mov"];
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos" parameters:parameters HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"result: %@, error: %@", result, error);
}];
```

What seems to be missing though is a way to show the upload progress.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct. Works here too. Strange. Maybe I didn't try this variant on 3.0.8 but 3.0.6b instead. Thank you for sharing.